# Routes config on next-routes

Tags: react-native, routes, next.js, js-routes

On my project, I'm using React + Next.js. For routes, I use the library next-routes. When you navigate the nested route `"{category alias}/filter"` the page reloads.

Add route - `routes.add ({name: 'products', pattern: '/:noname/filter', page: 'products'})`

Link to the route - `<Link route="category_alias/filter">Products</ Link>`

How to make it work without reloading?

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that you are still using the `Link` parameter inside the `next/link`

If that is so, then switch to using the `Link` object found the file where you export the next-routes

Assuming you have the `routes.js` file at the root of the project:

Then in a path like `pages/test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from '../routes';

export default function() {
    return (
        <Link route="/category_alias/filter">
            <a>Testing the microphone</a>
        </Link>
    );
}
```

See https://github.com/fridays/next-routes#on-the-client